# "Please update your Firestore Emulator"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

When running firebase emulators, the Firestore Requests tab gives me this message:

> **Please update your Firestore Emulator.**
> This feature requires the latest Firestore Emulator. Please upgrade your Firebase CLI to the latest version and refresh this page.

With a link [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#macos).

Following the directions and running

```bash
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash
```

gives me

```
-- Checking for existing firebase-tools on PATH...
Your machine already has firebase-tools@11.13.0 installed. Nothing to do.
-- All done!
```

So what do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Instead of posting to Stack Overflow, you should probably post an issue to GitHub so the engineers can evaluate. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I like to try here first so I don't bother the engineers until I'm sure it's not a configuration issue or just simply me doing something stupid. I see there's already an issue on github for this. I'll follow there.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5051

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Emulator is a `Java` app. So, just update `firebase-tools` to get emulators updated.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

That's works for me.